# Nested routes and url helper in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have nested routes which goes something like this:

```
resources :venues do
    #Halls
    get "hall/:id/exhibition" => "halls#exhibition", as: :exhibition
    get "hall/:id/visit" => "halls#visit", as: :hall_visit
    get "venue_structure", :to => "venues#venue_structure"
    resources :asset_types, :booths_tags, :tags, :uploaded_files, :events, :chats
    resources :halls do
        resources :webcasts
        resources :booths do
            resources :chats
        end
    end
end
```

Problem with this approach is that I have to put in three paramters in url helpers for nested ones like below:

```
venue_hall_booth_path(@booth.hall.venue, @booth.hall, @booth)
```

Is there a better approach to doing this other than me having to put in three different resources as parameters each time when I use this helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shallow routes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
resources :halls, shallow: true do
  resources :webcasts
  resources :booths do
    resources :chats
  end
end
```

This allows you access member urls without having to use the parent. Unless it's a `new` or `create` actions.

Or you can define them separately.

```
resources :booths do
  resources :chats
end
resources :halls do
  resources :webcasts
  resources :booths
end
```

Comment: which one is the best practice?

Comment: It depends on what suites your needs, but it's definitely best not to nest more than 2 levels. It becomes a headache on all levels, including testing. Imagine setting up the data to test the controller three levels down.

Comment: If it's nested a lot would shallow be more recomended as it's only one level?

Comment: You can `shallow` at any level. You don't have to use shallow, but some scenarios you have no choice. In my experience it depends on the situation. Security, access to parent objects, etc... But generally speaking I try to avoid nesting more than two levels unless it's necessary, which is rarely the case.